# TFS Build is failing all of a sudden - Error MSB4018

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs

We have a CI build and a nightly build which used to work perfectly but **all of a sudden it started failing**. I have been analyzing the log to see what the issue is but the log keeps complaining about random files already existing. The only common thing about these files is they are `.resx` files. I get this message:

> CoreResGen:
>   2017-01-29T05:01:39.1421685Z          Processing resource file "Resources\SomeRandFile.resx" into "obj\Release\Xxx.Model.Resources.SomeRandomResources.resources".
>
> '##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(550,5): Error MSB4018: The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.

Everything used to work and then one day it just stopped. I have spent a few days looking for this error and here are what I have tried so far:

1. Delete the *Windows\Temp* folder
2. Delete the *AppData\Local\Temp* folder
3. Turn the *Clean* flag on in the Repository tab.

and nothing is working.

Really appreciate if anyone has come across this and how you resolved it.

Just a note: The exact same code works locally on my dev machine. But fails on the build server.

Comment: WAG delete the build re-create the build pray it build

Comment: @Will what is WAG? sorry

Comment: Wild-ass guess.

Comment: Tried but unfortunately did not work.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use old XAML build or new tasks based build? How is the result if you configure a new build agent on another machine?

Comment: did you try after removing TFS caches?

Comment: @shawon if by tfs cache, you mean deleting temp folders yes.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT we are using task based builds. Not xaml

Comment: @CodingYoshi you can delete everything under "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\<version>\Cache". Also try re-install VNext agent . There has lots of VNext task updated recently and i found lots of version\cache related issue after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built an older changeset which was successfully built a few weeks ago to see if that will fail as well. I wanted to make sure it is not related to a checkin. As I expected, the build with that changeset failed with the same error. Ok good so at least we know it is not related to a checkin.

Then I created another build and kept modifying it to build a different a random project from my solution. My solution has around 50 projects so I started picking projects at random and built them. After a few builds the project which failed with the exact same error was my database project. Another small step towards the solution. Ok good we are getting somewhere.

I then installed the latest version of [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501) and tried rebuilding the project and it failed with the same error. Then, I installed Update 3 of VS 2015. Retried, failed again with the same error.

I found the `...\UserAccountUsedByTfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp` and decided to delete everything from it once again. Gave the build another try, failed with a different error:

> Error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\UserAccountUsedByTfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.SqlClrAttributes.cs' could not be found.

OK great! Different error. I just went into another user's temp folder and copied the following C# files:

1. .NETFramework,Version=v4.0.SqlClrAttributes
2. .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes
3. .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes

I ran the build again and YESSS IT PASSED!!

Then I ran the build for the whole solution and it passed too.

---

**CONCLUSION / SUMMARY**

1. Install the latest [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501)
2. Install the updates for VS 2015
3. Delete the temp file for the account used by TFS build (DO NOT delete the files starting with `.NETFramework...`)

Comment: Hi CodingYoshi - can you clarify "Delete the temp file for the account used by TFS build"?  Thanks!

Comment: @spottedmahn On your build server, you will find temp files in this location under the account used by the build process: `UserAccountUsedByTfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp`. You need to delete all the files except the ones in my answer.